# In Puppet, how can I access a variable/attribute inside a defined type?

Tags: puppet

I would like to reference variables inside instances of defined types. For example, what can I do to reference `$x` and `$y` of foo `a` in bar `b`?

```
 define foo($x, $y) {
  }

  define bar($foo) {
          notify { "${::$foo::x}": } # <- how to make this reference work?
  }

  foo { 'a':
          x => 'oh bar may you reference me',
          y => 'please'
  }

  bar { 'b':
          foo     => Foo['a'],
          require => Foo['a']
  }
```

The reason why I would like this to work is that a foo instance may contain many values that I wouldn't like to repeat to each and every resource that might need them. Instead of passing those values again and again, thus repeating myself, I'd rather pass a reference to their container.

I've been looking all over and tried a bunch of things, but can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere. I know it is possible to amend attributes, reference resources and read class attributes, but is it possible to read attributes of a resource/defined type? If it isn't what is then the best possible work around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've actually just found out that [Puppetlab's stdlib module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib) includes a [getparam function](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#getparam) that can be used to solve this problem.

So here is finally the solution to my own question:

```
define foo($x, $y) {
}

define bar($foo) {
  notify { getparam(Foo[$foo], 'x'): }
  notify { getparam(Foo[$foo], 'y'): }
}

foo { 'a':
  x => 'oh bar may you reference me',
  y => 'please'
}

bar { 'b':
  foo  => 'a'
}
```

Please note that the `require => Foo['a']` in the definition of `Bar['b']` does not appear to be needed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that you can access a defined type's attributes. [Possible explanation here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scope_and_puppet.html). What you can do however, is externalize it via hiera.

Hiera is a great way to separate your manifest logic from the data populating it, but it is not difficult to set up.

[Installing](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/installing.html)

In my first try I was trying to access hiera variables by class reference; `foo::a` for example, but that doesn't work for defined types.

Using http://drewblessing.com/blog/-/blogs/puppet-hiera-implement-defined-resource-types-in-hiera as a guide, you can put declare all those attributes in hiera with a simple config:

[Configuring](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/configuring.html):

hiera.yaml

```
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: $hiera_dir
:hierarchy:
  - common
```

$hiera_dir/common.yaml

```
foo:
  a:
    x: 'oh bar may you reference me'
    y: 'please'
```

And then in your puppet manifest:

```
define foo ($x, $y) {
}

define bar($foo) {
    require create_my_foos

    $all_foos = hiera('foo')

    # This is just for proof of concept, to show that the variable can be passed.
    file { '/tmp/output.txt':
        content => $all_foos[$foo]['x']
    }
}

class create_my_foos {  
    $foo_instances = hiera('foo', [])
    create_resources('foo', $foo_instances)
}

bar { 'b':
    foo => 'a'
}
```

Now you can access foo's variables by calling the `hiera('foo')` function to get an array of `foo`'s attributes, and do array lookups to get the exact parameter you need.

Note that hiera [only looks up **top-level keys**](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#interacting-with-structured-data-from-hiera), so you can't do `hiera('foo'['a']['x])`.

Comment: Certainly not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks! I've tried your workaround and it does work. I will accept your answer with bounty unless somebody else can come up with a way of accessing foo.x without the requirement that foo.x is accessible through hiera within the next couple of days.

Comment: I am also curious as to why this is not possible using the Puppet language alone.

Comment: I am also quite interested in why, so I did a bit more digging around and found something of interest - http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scope_and_puppet.html I have updated my answer to include it.

Comment: I actually read this before, but this article doesn't seem to explain why.  I am guessing it has something to do with that Puppet runs all its functions and interpret all its variables during what I would call compile-time.

Comment: I found a way! See my answer.