# Can I access a resource's attribute(s) within a manifest from outside the resource?

Tags: puppet

In Puppet 3, I would like to be able to branch within a manifest based on the installed version of an RPM package. I figured it would be as simple as looking up the `version` (or `ensure`?) attribute on the package resource and using that in a conditional expression. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get a resource's attributes from outside the resource, even after combing through the reference manual.

Comment: it is not possible, as @mrhobo says. the point is that in puppet you describe what is your desired state (and nothing else); here you are telling puppet that your desired states depends on what is already installed in the machine. that's not the purpose of puppet.

Comment: It's not really a case of what's already installed, but of what's _going to be_ installed from an available RPM repo, one that I don't control. (But maybe that is a better way to address the problem--put the RPMs in a place where I have control over them.)

Comment: ok i see. yes, your manifest should state which version of the rpm package you want (stated in the code, in hiera or somewhere else); and then, you can branch based on that version. if you cannot use the standard package puppet resource to install the package (are you sure of that? the puppet package resource can be configured: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package), you could install it with a puppet exec: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to access a resource's attribute. Have a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013084/in-puppet-how-can-i-access-a-variable-attribute-inside-a-defined-type) I recently asked. If you base your package version on a class attribute, hiera data or [both](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup) you can use those to base your condition on.