# Access parameter from a resource defined using create_resources

Tags: puppet

I would like to know if it is possible to access a parameter from a class being instantiated using the create_resources function. I want to use that parameter in other class to conditionally install some things or not.

This is my scenario:

```
define myResource($myParam) { ... }

create_resources(myResource, $hashResources)

$hashResources = { "MyResource1" : { "myParam" : 1 },
                   "MyResource2" : { "myParam" : 2 }
                 }

myFancyPuppetClass($nameOfResource) {
 if(******myParam from the resource defined with name $nameOfResource in the same catalog******) { ... }
}
```

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do the reference? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resources you are attempting to create are defined types, and the parameters in a defined resource are not accessible, this is not possible in the latest version of Puppet.

See a previous answer of mine regarding [accessing parameters in defined resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013084/in-puppet-how-can-i-access-a-variable-attribute-inside-a-defined-type/19133150#19133150) for an alternative.