# Read values from puppet template

Tags: ruby, templates, erb, puppet

Hi I've a puppet template with below values.

```
myfile.erb
name = "abc"
desg = "engineer"
Sal = "10000"
```

And I try to read these values from my puppet script like below

```
init.pp
    $value = template("d:/puppet/modules/mymodule/templates/myfile.erb")


now my $value is containing all values from the myfile.erb file. Is there any way to divide the values like $value[0], $value[1] etc..
```

I want to display only "abc" "engineer" "1000"

Answer (score 2):

When your data lookup starts getting complicated, I highly recommend you move away from templates towards an external data lookup, like `hiera`. For a guide to setting up, I've written a small tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013084/in-puppet-how-can-i-access-a-variable-attribute-inside-a-defined-type/19133150#19133150). You can substitute `yaml` for `json`.

Your hiera file could look as simple as this:

```
{
    "myfile": {
        "name": "abc",
        "desg": "engineer"
        "Sal": "10000"
    }
}
```

And then in your file:

```
$vars = hiera('myfile')

// Gives "abc"
$vars['name']

// Gives "engineer"
$vars['desg']
```